How to make DatabaseLink` use the newer version of the driver
I want to use the latest version of a driver but I don't have admin permission on the system so I can't delete the older version of the .jar file and replace with the new one here:

C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Wolfram Desktop\13.3\SystemFiles\Links\DatabaseLink\Java

and also newer version of library in:

C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Wolfram Desktop\13.3\SystemFiles\Links\DatabaseLink\Java\Libraries\Windows

So what option do I have?
I tried adding .jar file to the classpath using:
AddToClassPath[...]

But since DatabaseLink`  automatically adds the older .jar file to the classpath. Even if I ReinstallJava[ClassPath->...] it still uses the older .jar file located here:

C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Wolfram Desktop\13.3\SystemFiles\Links\DatabaseLink\Java

Is there something I can do in the OpenSQLConnection to specify the full path of .jar file to grab the class from?
OpenSQLConnection[JDBC[...class...,...connection string with protocol...]]

Or some exposed documented or internal undocumented function or variable to allow Databaselink`  to target a custom location first rather than the default "C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Wolfram Desktop\13.3\SystemFiles\Links\DatabaseLink\Java" when searching for .jar file and accompanying .dll.
